# Installation from a hard drive

Tags: system-installation

On my laptop the dvd/cd drive is broken and it does not boot from a usb port. So can I install Ubuntu from the hard drive and if so how?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot

Comment: If you have an existing linux system, you can chroot into the new disk to install ubuntu that way https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromLinux and here is more helpful stuff https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebootstrapChroot

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromLinux

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have Windows, you can use Plop Boot Manager - https://www.plop.at/en/bootmanager/download.html . Follow the instructions here - https://www.raymond.cc/blog/doing-the-impossible-boot-computer-from-usb-or-cdrom-even-if-bios-not-supported-using-plop/ . Once you installed the Plop and rebooted, select it and another menu will appear where you can choose "USB".